# Значение что в себе несёт FormData()?

Tags: formdata, javascript

Вот хотелось бы узнать про объект `FormData();` в `js`. Многие подумают послать меня в гугл, но я только от туда.

Все, что я нашел более менее по [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Но там мало информации о нем, о русскоязычных сайтах я вообще молчу, там в основном примеры загрузки файла через ajax, но никак нет более подробного пояснение о этом объекте.

Меня конкретно интересует значение что в себе он несет.

Comment: вторая ссылка в поиске по запросу FormData http://true-coder.ru/php/ispolzovanie-obekta-formdata-dlya-zagruzki-fajlov.html

Comment: @mountpoint как я и говорил ранее "о русскоязычных сайтах я вообще молчу, там в основном примеры загрузки файла через ajax, но никак нет более подробного пояснение о этом объекте."

Мне жу нужно узнать что хранит объкт

Comment: @M11, FormData — это host-объект, какую информацию вы хотите узнать? Если очень просто, то данный объект хранит в себе данные по принципу: ключ — название поля, значение — строка, либо ссылка на Blob.

Comment: хотел бы добавить, что это коллекция на самом деле. т.е. не одну запись хранит а массивоподобный список таких записей. [вот тут](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata) почему-то даже понятнее чем на mdn.  [тут тоже ](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/file/xhr2/) про этот объект рассказывается.

> там в основном примеры загрузки файла через ajax

а что вы хотели если это часть спецификации XMLHttpRequest2 ?

Comment: @RubaXa @eicto если говорить уж точно то мне нужно вывести картинку на экран которую выбрал пользователь, но до того как он ее загрузит на сервер.

Я не знал что не все так просто, прошу простить что говорил не точно.

Есть такая часть скрипта
 
     http://pastebin.com/z1EwLhNb

Пересмотрев код я понял, что DataForm не извлекает данные о файле, а просто является "правильным хранилищем" для передачи данных.

Верно понял?

Если так то вопрос изначально поставлен неверно.

input типа file создает свой массив, как мне узнать значение которые он хранит?

Comment: Для этого вам нужно создать на него виртуальную ссылку через [URL.createObjectURL][2], либо прочесть файл как DataURI при помощи [FileReader][1]

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader
[2]:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL